# The amazing logo effect about google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

Better use chrome to open this site,any webkit browser may do too.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

You can see the amazing effect about that chrome logo when you put mouse on it.
I download the source of that page, but unfortunately got lost in it.

It uses non-standard css `-webkit-mask` and `-webkit-gradient` like below:

```
-webkit-mask: "-webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, %s, 17 17, %s," + "from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))," + "color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2))," + "to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)))"
```

then change the parameter %s

If the logo is big enough we should see a white circle getting bigger and bigger from the center.

I tried to use jquery but cannot make it.Can someone help?

Comment: So you're struggling to animate the gradient in jQuery? If you apply that style to an element (changing the `%s`) it doesn't move, which is right. You could do this in a `-webkit-animation` I believe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can animate it with jQuery by using an interval and adjusting those properties like so:

```
var radius = 0;

var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#chrome").css("-webkit-mask", "-webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, " + radius + ", 17 17, " + (radius + 15) + ", from(rgb(0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgb(0, 0, 0)))");
    radius++;
    if (radius === 124) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 20);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sync/WHAXg/

Comment: Thanks Ben,your answer is very explicit,especially the link,wonderful.

Comment: Thanks :) I improved the code a little since I first posted too, now only one variable 'radius' so it's a little clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I modified the answer of ben to use the jQuery [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function like this:

```
$({ inner_radius : 0 }).animate({ inner_radius : 123 },{ step : function(A){
    var delta_radius = 15;
    $("#chrome").css("-webkit-mask","-webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, "+inner_radius+", 17 17, "+(inner_radius+delta_radius)+", from(rgb(0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgb(0, 0, 0)))");
}, duration : 2000 });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WHAXg/2/)

Comment: Thanks,this one looks more concise and pure jquery.