# How this hovering effect is done in google chrome page?

Tags: css, google-chrome

How this hovering effect is done in google chrome page, when u hover over this chrome logo in the below given link?

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/

Comment: View source (Ctrl+U) / Developer tools -> Sources -> Scripts / Right-click, Inspect element.

Comment: The question has been already answered in stackoverflow itself. check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854905/the-amazing-logo-effect-about-google-chrome).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854905/the-amazing-logo-effect-about-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like it initially has the style :

```
-webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, 123, 17 17, 138, from(rgb(0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgb(0, 0, 0)));
```

And on hover, the gradient quickly goes from:

```
-webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, 0, 17 17, 0,
```

And back to its original state.

How it executes this affect is cloudy. I would imagine it implements Javascript and on hover, resets the gradient and does some sort of loop that says while those numbers are less than the original, increase

Answer (score 0):

I made an angular plugin for this: http://x1a0.net/angular-shiny/

(only works for webkit browsers for now)